# Default SPEmailEventReceiver: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: event-receivers, debugging

I'm trying to write a new Email Event Receiver for an email-enabled document library. When my feature is disabled, email is delivered successfully to the library. When my feature is enabled, this appears in the UCS logs:

**UCS Log**

```
Loading and running the event receiver class MyEmailHandler.MyMetadataExtractionEventHandler.MyMetadataExtractionEventHandler from assembly MyEmailHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=49f071f6ad2c11c6 failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**EventReceiver**

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace MyEmailHandler.MyMetadataExtractionEventHandler
{
    public class MyMetadataExtractionEventHandler : SPEmailEventReceiver
    {
        public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, String receiverData)
        {
            base.EmailReceived(list, emailMessage, receiverData);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to SharePoint development so don't know what to do next to debug this. I tried following the instructions on this page under [Debugging Feature Event Receivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798479.aspx) and put the breakpoint on the `base.EmailReceived(...)` line, but the breakpoint was never triggered.

Comment: Which process are you attaching to debug code? you should not attach w3wp.exe instead you should attach owstimer.exe process to debug your receiver. (Note that you have deployed visual studio solution in debug mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow these steps

1.Deploy your solution to SharePoint.

2.Press `Windows+R` and run  `Services.msc`, Restart `SharePoint Timer Service`

3.Go back to visual studio attach process `OWSTIMER.EXE` and try sending mail to document library/list

NOTE: you will have to stop and start `SharePoint Timer Service` every time you deploy solution to Sharepoint.

when you send email check the `drop` folder (`C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop`) does the mail gets stuck there?

Comment: Instead of sending email, I'm just copying and pasting an old .eml into the drop folder. It gets picked up after 30-60 seconds regardless of if my feature is enabled or not. I'll run through your steps later today and come back to share success or other issues.

Comment: sure let me know

Comment: These steps allowed debugging of the function in question. The error itself seems to be that the base.EmailReceived method is blank and isn't doing something that SharePoint expects it to. More details about this can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2009/05/13/attachments-disappear-with-custom-email-event-handler.aspx

Comment: The relevant section of the blog link from my comment above: If you are planning to implement your own EmailHandler, you will need to take care of all the default functionality also provided by SharePoint, including checking user permissions, dealing with duplicate files, and saving the original email.