# Debugging an SP Feature in production

Tags: feature, debugging

I have developed an SP Feature in C# and tested in development environment, confirming it is functioning correctly.

When I publish to production and enable on a site, I just get a single line in the ULS log when it triggers:

> Loading and running the event receiver class TCBSEmailHandler.TCBSMetadataExtractionEventHandler.TCBSMetadataExtractionEventHandler from assembly TCBSEmailHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=49f071f6ad2c11c6 failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What can I do in the production environment to debug this error?

A similar question of mine regarding debugging in development was answered [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145065/default-spemaileventreceiver-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje), but I'm not sure if/how I could apply similar logic to a deployed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be debugging in production. Instead, add additional logging capabilities to your app and do more defensive coding. By defensive coding, I mean that if your code is calling some method to get an object, check to see if you got the object before doing anything with it.

Comment: Fair enough. I was already trying logging and that was failing so I was looking for another way around it. I've asked a new question to target the logging issue I'm having [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148102/custom-uls-logging-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio ultimate to develop your feature IntelliTrace would be an option. IntelliTrace team done a great job to plugin SharePoint events with IntelliTrace .