# Custom ULS logging not working

Tags: feature, uls

I've tried to add custom ULS logging to my SP Feature, the feature code runs correctly and I can see the results in my library, but none of the logging appears to occur. I've based this off a few online blogs (listed at the end), have I done something wrong? I'm viewing the ULS log through ULSViewer.

```
    private void writeLog(string log)
    {
        SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0,
            new SPDiagnosticsCategory("TCBS Email Handler", TraceSeverity.Medium, EventSeverity.Information),
            TraceSeverity.Medium,
            "TCBS: {0}",
            new object[] { log }
        );
    }

    public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, String receiverData)
    {
        writeLog("Beginning metadata extraction.");
        ...
    }
```

Blogs used as reference:

- http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2010/04/17/how-to-write-custom-logs-into-uls-logs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the code using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`. This way code will get executed using App pool account. If the app pool account is part of the group *Performance Log Users*, the code will be able to write in the ULS logs.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make ULS logging work for a AppPool account that is not Administrator you have to add your AppPool user to "Performance Log Users" group.

And restart the Application Pool that is using this AppPool account.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect, I first tried adding the user that runs OWSTIMER to it, and then I added the Everyone group to it, restarted SharePoint and tried again, my custom logs still aren't appearing in the ULS logs. Is there any other configuration I might need to do in Central Admnistration to allow custom logging?

Comment: Please cross check the central admin configuration from "http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/debugging-using-spdiagnosticsservice-in-sharepoint-2010/"